# find count of individual items in a nested tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tuple which contains nested tuples. what is the simplest way to find the total number of individual items in the tuples. I am using python 3

The tuple looks like

```
(('BCG', 'OPV 0', 'Hep-B 1'), ('DTwP 1', 'IPV 1', 'Hep-B 2', 'Hib 1', 'Rotavirus 1', 'PCV 1'), ('DTwP 2', 'IPV 2', 'Hib 2', 'Rotavirus 2', 'PCV 2'), ('DTwP 3', 'IPV 3', 'Hib 3', 'Rotavirus 3', 'PCV 3'), ('OPV 1', 'Hep-B 3'), ('OPV 2', 'MMR-1'), ('Typhoid', 'Conjugate Vaccine'), 'Hep-A 1', ('MMR 2', 'Varicella 1', 'PCV booster'), ('DTwP B1/DTaP B1', 'IPV B1, Hib B1'), 'Hep-A 2', 'Typhoid booster', ('DTwP B2/DTaP B2', 'OPV 3', 'Varicella 2', 'Typhoid booster'), ('Tdap/Td', 'HPV'))
```

I want total of all items in the tuple

Comment: If the same item appears in different tuples , do you still want to count them as single item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean each individual item in the entire data set, you could easily do this:

```
data = (('BCG', 'OPV 0', 'Hep-B 1'), ...)
unique = len(set(x for inner in data for x in inner))
```

That's it.

It works by iterating through each inner tuple, then through each item in each of those. Adds them to a set (all items must be unique) and then counting how big that set is.

Edit: Perhaps I misunderstood "individual items", I thought you were looking to ignore duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You have a tuple of tuples of and want to know how many items in it.  This counts them:

```
>>> t = (('BCG', 'OPV 0', 'Hep-B 1'), ('DTwP 1', 'IPV 1', 'Hep-B 2', 'Hib 1', 'Rotavirus 1', 'PCV 1'), ('DTwP 2', 'IPV 2', 'Hib 2', 'Rotavirus 2', 'PCV 2'), ('DTwP 3', 'IPV 3', 'Hib 3', 'Rotavirus 3', 'PCV 3'), ('OPV 1', 'Hep-B 3'), ('OPV 2', 'MMR-1'), ('Typhoid', 'Conjugate Vaccine'), 'Hep-A 1', ('MMR 2', 'Varicella 1', 'PCV booster'), ('DTwP B1/DTaP B1', 'IPV B1, Hib B1'), 'Hep-A 2', 'Typhoid booster', ('DTwP B2/DTaP B2', 'OPV 3', 'Varicella 2', 'Typhoid booster'), ('Tdap/Td', 'HPV'))
>>> sum(len(x) for x in t)
65
```

`t` is the tuple of tuples.  `x` is each of the tuples in `t`.  This sums the lengths of all the `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = (('BCG', 'OPV 0', 'Hep-B 1'), ('DTwP 1', 'IPV 1', 'Hep-B 2', 'Hib 1', 'Rotavirus 1', 'PCV 1'), ('DTwP 2', 'IPV 2', 'Hib 2', 'Rotavirus 2', 'PCV 2'), ('DTwP 3', 'IPV 3', 'Hib 3', 'Rotavirus 3', 'PCV 3'), ('OPV 1', 'Hep-B 3'), ('OPV 2', 'MMR-1'), ('Typhoid', 'Conjugate Vaccine'), 'Hep-A 1', ('MMR 2', 'Varicella 1', 'PCV booster'), ('DTwP B1/DTaP B1', 'IPV B1, Hib B1'), 'Hep-A 2', 'Typhoid booster', ('DTwP B2/DTaP B2', 'OPV 3', 'Varicella 2', 'Typhoid booster'), ('Tdap/Td', 'HPV'))
sum(map(lambda  x:len(x),t))
```